# How to free a control in its own event?

Tags: delphi, events, controls, firemonkey, free

I have a list of `TPanels` in a FMX application and I want to free a panel if I click on it.

To free them directly in the Onclick-handler is not the right way, because I get an access-violation. And I don't want to use `windowsmessages` (recommended in [How to free control inside its event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502565/how-to-free-control-inside-its-event-handler) and [Why does my program crash when I destroy a button in its own OnClick handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359552/why-does-my-program-crash-when-i-destroy-a-button-in-its-own-onclick-handler)) because it is a firemonkey application and I do not know how these messages work on android and mac.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`myObject.Release`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Release):

> Marks this TFmxObject object for delayed deletion.

Immediate actions in this method:

- set Parent = nil
- insert object into delayed delete list

Delayed action:

- free object from list (`vPurgatory`).

Remember, that method `Free` (and procedure `FreeAndNil`) does not remove the object itself in mobile platforms:

> // under ARC, this method isn't actually called since the compiler translates
>   // the call to be a mere nil assignment to the instance variable, which then calls _InstClear

Comment: Thank you for your comment to my now deleted answer, much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for fast help. @David Heffernan: What is the main difference between your solution (TThread.Queue) and kami's? I think the 'release' is more elegant but at the end they do the same or not?

Comment: The main difference is that TThread.Queue does not work. It doesn't delay execution and is executed synchronously. It's just a brain freeze on my part.

Comment: Note that in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo using Android, `Release` calls `TThread.ForceQueue`, which is broken. See [How to release a Firemonkey control properly, in this case a child form with a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49159986/576719).