# How to release a Firemonkey control properly, in this case a child form with a parent?

Tags: android, delphi, automatic-ref-counting, firemonkey

From inside an event handler of the control itself, I would like to delete and free it.

A typical use case for `TFmxObject.Release`, isn't it? However, it only seems to work under Windows, but not Android, and this method is now *deprecated* anyway.

I know, *doesn't work* is not a good problem description, but currently I'm not able to debug it under android. Under Windows, I see that the event handler continues correctly after the `.Release` and after it finished, my log message inside my controls destructor is executed. Under Android, the application hangs.

When I use `.Free` instead, it still works under Windows (destructor happens immediately, but the handler doesn't access the control after the free), and in Android there is no visible problem, but the destructor is never called, so I have a leak.

With `.DisposeOf` the effect is the same as with `.Release` - Windows ok, Android hangs.

I also tried `MyParent.RemoveComponent(MyControl)` but it all didn't help.

What else do I have to do to release all references so that ARC can do its work? Or how else?

Comment: If you are using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, you could use [TThread.ForceQueue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) to execute code later. `TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure begin // Dispose of the control
 end);`

Comment: That's exactly what `.Release` does. It seems that unter Android this is executed immediately and not later, and that's also why a `.DisposeOf` without Queue behaves the same. I just tested exactly that myself...

Comment: Another bug in the RTL, I assume. Please file a QP report.

Comment: Can you solve it by creating an anonymous thread and inside dispose of the control in a queue method?

Comment: One solution would be to use native development tools.......

Comment: @LURD, that doesn't sound like something I should really try. I took a simple timer instead. It works, but of course it's a really bad workaround and I'm hoping for more answers here :)

Comment: You might want to describe *why* you want to do it in an event handler of the form itself, as opposed to doing it from outside the form

Comment: @LURD: "*creating an anonymous thread and inside dispose of the control in a queue method*" - that would be the way to do it before `ForceQueue()` was introduced, if not using `Release()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, since `Release` calls `ForceQueue` and `ForceQueue` does not work properly in Android, wrapping it up in a thread/queue combination should do the trick.

Comment: @LURD: can you absolutely confirm that `ForceQueue()` is broken on Android? Last year I updated Indy to support `ForceQueue()`, and now I'm probably going to have to disable it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I can't confirm it. (I have given up mobile for now). But the OP seems to have concluded this. If maf_soft could provide a simple test case, others can confirm it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ForceQueue is currently broken on Android. Anonymous thread + Queue or Synchronize works.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Is there a QP # for it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau None that I know about.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: nevermind, I found one: [RSP-17841 TThread.ForceQueue not work in Android](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17841)

Comment: says it was fixed in 10.3 Rio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TFmxObject.Release` uses `TThread.ForceQueue` internally, and that's currently broken under Android (see discussion above).

As a workaround, a working cross-platform version for releasing an object from its event handler would be

```
procedure TForm.CloseBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Parent := nil;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Self.DisposeOf;
    end);
  end).Start;
end;
```

What is important to keep in mind is that you should not keep any other references to the control you are releasing or you may hit the trouble down the road.

Update for 10.4 and newer versions:

Since 10.4 and unified memory management `DisposeOf` is now equivalent to `Free` on all platforms and `Self.DisposeOf` can be replaced with `Self.Free`.

Comment: I would use `TThread.Queue()` instead of `TThread.Synchronize()`

Comment: It was @LURD's workaround idea and I didn't like it, but you convinced me with high quality tested code, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner... been busy... your question was fine as-is, though now it is even better. Thanks for editing my answer :)

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17841 says that issue was fixed in 10.3 Rio

Comment: Is there a proof about  "Self.DisposeOf can be replaced with Self.Free."? Thank you.

Comment: @alitrun https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#Unified_Memory_Management there is no ARC compiler and in classic compiler `DisposeOf` always called Free see `TObject.DisposeOf` in System unit.

Comment: Yes, DisposeOf calls Free, but not Free calls DisposeOf.

Comment: @alitrun `DisposeOf` was introduced for ARC compiler and there is no more ARC compiler and the different implementation for ARC is no longer used, so calling either `DisposeOf` or `Free`  will run same code at the end.  You can still use `DisposeOf`, but there is no need and you can just use `Free` everywhere.